# Hibernate fetch related table with criteria

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

User enters "test" keyword and I try to select cities and markets in these cities by these criterias:

may be none of the markets contains "test" but only city at this time select only city.Or may be city name doesn't contain "test" but markets contain at that time select that city and fetch markets which contains in that city

My code is this:

```
  Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(City.class);

  criteria.createAlias("marketList", "marketInCity");

  Criterion citySearch = Restrictions.like("name", name, MatchMode.ANYWHERE);
  Criterion marketSearch= Restrictions.like("marketInCity.name", name, MatchMode.ANYWHERE);

  criteria.add(Restrictions.or(citySearch, marketSearch));

  criteria.setFetchMode("marketList", FetchMode.JOIN).add(
        Restrictions.like("marketInCity.name", name, MatchMode.ANYWHERE)
);

  criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

as result i can get all cities which city name contains "test" or at least one of the markets name contains "test" but select all markets

what is the problem in my code how can i fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, such cases is easy to debug when you'll see SQL code (i.e. set `hibernate.show_sql=true` and you'll see what exactly going on).

At least one issue in your code:

```
criteria.createAlias("marketList", "marketInCity");
```

it's the same as

```
criteria.createAlias("marketList", "marketInCity", JoinType.INNER_JOIN);
```

Try to fix to

```
criteria.createAlias("marketList", "marketInCity", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
```